# function breaks if id doesn't come

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Error : Cannot read property id of undefined**

How can I re-write this function so that it doesn't break foundApplication[0].id, if id doesn't come or foundApplication array comes empty?

I cannot alter getDocument function

```
  async function getApplicationByCbaxUid(cbaxUid) {
    let foundApplication = await dbService.application
      .find({ userID: cbaxUid });
    return getDocument(foundApplication[0].id);
  }
```

Comment: Did you debug this? What was the value of foundApplication? How about foundApplication[0]?

Comment: it was empty. [] @jarmod

Comment: @art if it was empty then [0] is undefined and undefined.id is an error

Comment: You can't get an element from an empty array (which has length of 0). If the array is empty then you cannot call getDocument and you need to do something else, like throw an error or simply ignore the failure (if that's appropriate in your app).

Comment: Just use a `if` statement or `foundApplication?.[0]?.id` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate if the array and the id exist. if you're using latest version of ES, you can use optional chaining (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
  async function getApplicationByCbaxUid(cbaxUid) {
    let foundApplication = await dbService.application
      .find({ userID: cbaxUid });
    return getDocument(foundApplication?.[0]?.id);
  }
```

if you don't

```js
  async function getApplicationByCbaxUid(cbaxUid) {
    let foundApplication = await dbService.application
      .find({ userID: cbaxUid });
    return foundApplication.length && foundApplication[0].id && getDocument(foundApplication[0].id);
  }
```

This is doing all the normal validations which the latest operator (optional chaining is doing)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a check if the array is empty

```
return foundApplication.length ? getDocument(foundApplication[0].id) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

set an if statement and add whatever you need to do if it fails to the else block

```
async function getApplicationByCbaxUid(cbaxUid) {
let foundApplication = await dbService.application
  .find({ userID: cbaxUid });
if(foundApplication.length){
  return getDocument(foundApplication[0].id)
}else{
   ...do what you want here
}
```

}